# Layer object c#

Tags: c#

I create a panel and fill it on all the surface of the form and i create a label too for bring it to front of the panel but the only thing it's showing is the panel, i see the hitbox of the label that's all.

```
        private void drawPanels()
    {
        // I setup my label
        Label username = new Label();
        Label usernameText = new Label();
        var usernameSize = new Size(84, 21);
        var usernamePos = new Point(11, 4);
        int usernameOffset = 60;


        // I setup my panel here
        Panel panel = new Panel();
        var panelSize = new Size(490, 50);
        var panelPos = new Point(12, 12);
        int panelVertOffset = 60;

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            // I draw the panel
            panel.Size = panelSize;
            panel.Location = panelPos;
            panel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(35, 35, 35);
            parent.Controls.Add(panel);
            parent.Controls.Add(username);

            // I draw the label
            username.Size = new Size(84, 21);
            username.Location = new Point(11, 4);
            username.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(35, 35, 35);
            username.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(35, 35, 35);
            username.Text = "Username:";

            // Im trying to fix the problem with this function but it isn't work
            username.BringToFront();

            // Duplicate the panel and place it down ( y+60 )
            panelPos.Offset(0, panelVertOffset);
            usernamePos.Offset(0, usernameOffset);
        }
    }
```

[That's the result i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utqhi.png)

Comment: I think the problem is that your text color(`ForeColor`) is same as background and hence even though label is on top, you cannot see its text. Change the `ForeColor` to some light color and see if it helps.

Comment: What are you targeting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: Mat J just a little error of mine when i tried to fix but it's not this.

Comment: @TaW im doing windows form.

Comment: I suggest you look into how to create a Custom Control. You can have multiple objects (text boxes, labels, lists, whatever) in one object. The cc takes care of laying itself out. You can add multiple copies of the cc to your form. [Developing Custom Windows Forms Controls with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/developing-custom-windows-forms-controls?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: Uhm ok, i will try this